# Implications of adding enctype="multipart/form-data" in a master page?

Tags: asp.net

We have one master page for an entire asp.net 2.0 site, which contains the form tag.

Are there any implications to adding enctype to the form tag?  One page needs to be able to upload a file, and I believe this is required in order for that to function properly.  Do we need to re-test the entire site after making this change?

Prior to this, the form tag was simply:

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
```

Comment: I think it will mess up with `Request.Form` which would be sent in binary format, so something like `Request.Form["textbox1"]` might stop working

Comment: Is there any documentation for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use code to programmatically set the attributes of form tag. And you can put the code in a proper page event such as "Init" event.

e.g.

```
public partial class test_TestContentPage : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We did that a while back and never gave it another thought.

Our main app has literally hundreds of pages all with various input controls (text, multiline, drop down lists, checkboxes, etc) and we've never seen an issue.

Comment: We have some pages with very large viewstate, and I'm concerned that it may add additional overhead because of that.